Solving PDE in Oppenheimer-Snyder article "On Continued Gravitational Contraction"
I'm working on this article for my degree thesis and I struggling to understand how they solved the PDE on the equation (31) for the interior part. I'll give some details about it.
The topic is they have a solution for the metric in a set of co-moving coordinates $(R,\tau)$ and they are trying to make a variable change to a set of coordinates $(r,t)$. That means finding the expressions for $r=r(R,\tau)$ and $t=t(R,\tau)$.
The $r$ one is
$r=r(r,\tau)=R(1-\frac{3}{2}\tau)^{2/3}$
and to obtain the $t$ function they arrive at the PDE:
$\frac{t'}{\dot{t}}=r'\dot{r}$
in which primes are derivatives in $R$ and dots, in $\tau$. Looking at the expression for $r$ they get
$\dot{r}=-\frac{R^{3/2}}{r^{1/2}} \hspace{1cm} r'=\frac{r}{R}$
and substituting, the PDE ends like
$\frac{t'}{\dot{t}}=r'\dot{r}=-R^{1/2}r^{1/2}=-R\left(1-\frac{3}{2}\tau\right)^{1/3}$
They claim that the general solution for this equation is
$t=L(y)$
with $L$ being a general function and
$y=\frac{1}{2}\left(R^2-1\right)+\frac{r}{R}$
but I have no idea why and how they arrived to this result. I'd really appreciate some help and I can give more details if needed.

Can you attach a link to the article?

@Conreu sure, here it goes https://journals.aps.org/pr/pdf/10.1103/PhysRev.56.455. To understand better the equations I've eliminated the $R_b$ and $r_0$ terms from the article, which are just parameters.

Your PDE is
$$\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial R}+ R\,\bigl(1-\frac{3}{2}\tau\bigr)^{1/3}\frac{\partial }{\partial \tau}\right) t=0.$$
It is a special case of a PDE of the form
$$\sum_{i=1}^n v^i\frac{\partial }{\partial x^i}F = 0$$
(where $v^i$ are given functions of variables $x^1,\dots, x^n$ and $F$ is the unknown function), which says that $F$ is constant along the flowlines of the vector field $\sum_{i=1}^n v^i\frac{\partial }{\partial x^i}$, and so we just need to find these flowlines, i.e. to solve the system of ODEs
$$\frac{dx^i}{ds} = v^i(x^1,\dots, x^n).$$
(It is the simplest case of what is called the method of characteristics).
In your case the ODE is
$$\frac{dR}{ds}=1,\quad \frac{d\tau}{ds}=R\,\bigl(1-\frac{3}{2}\tau\bigr)^{1/3}$$
so $s=R$ (up to an inessential constant), the ODE is
$$R\,dR=\bigl(1-\frac{3}{2}\tau\bigr)^{-1/3}\,d\tau $$
and its solution is
$$\frac12 R^2 + (1-\frac{3}{2}\tau\bigr)^{2/3}=\textit{const} $$
These curves are the flowlines, so your function $t$ should be constant on each of them, i.e. it should be a function of $\frac12 R^2 + (1-\frac{3}{2}\tau\bigr)^{2/3}$.

Thank you very very much. Your explanation was super fast and super clear. Have a nice day
